# Using Greasemonkey to edit a URL with a specific id value

Tags: javascript, url, greasemonkey

I have a number of links on a website and there is one link that I would like to edit the URI of. The one specific link has a specific id="foo" value that sets it apart from all of the other links - and there is only one link on the page with that specific id value.

I would simply like to change the uri from (for instance:) http://example.com/   to  http://example.com/foo/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide more details. And, a link to the target page is a good idea.

Based on the info provided so far, here is a simple script that demonstrates how to change a link URL:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Change a specific link
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==

var targID      = "foo";
var targLink    = document.querySelector ("#" + targID);
targLink.href  += targID + "\/";
```